# Am having issues grabbing the the value from the url using GET superglobal in model view controller method

Tags: php, model-view-controller

hello guys please i need your help. I am working on an mvc php pattern, everything is already done the only thing i want to check now is how i can get access to the user profile this way: http:://localhost:3000/profile?u=werner

But its really giving me a hard time to figure it out. ive tried evry format possible for it to work but not working. let me post the following code
This is the router file where i created all the routes

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

class Route
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        include 'Routes.php';
    }

    public static function get(string $path, callable $method)
    {
         // if( method_exists($method, $path) ) {
        //     echo"method does not exist";
        // }
        

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $path) {

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'GET') {
                exit('This path accepts only GET requests');
            }
            return $method();
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $path) {
                echo"method does not exist";
            }  
        }
    }

    public static function post(string $path, callable $method)
    {

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $path) {
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
                exit('This path accepts only POST requests');
            }
            return $method();
        }
    }

    public static function view(string $path, ?array $props = null)
    {
        if (!\file_exists('resources/views/' . $path . '.php')) {
            return static::view('404');
        }

        if (isset($props)) {
            foreach ($props as $key => $value) {
                ${$key} = $value;
            }
        }
        require_once 'resources/views/' . $path . '.php';
    }
    
}
```

The route.php helps to check whether its a post or get request now moving on to the profile controller
This is the profile controller:
<?php

```
namespace App\Controllers;
require_once 'app/Models/User.php';
use App\Models\User;

use App\Classes\Route;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public static function profile($email)
    {
        $email = $_GET['u'];
        echo $emaii;

       echo"this is it";
    }
}
```

Now the web.php is where the declared methods pass through with the method either get or post request as show below
This is the web.php:

```
<?php

namespace Routes;

use App\Classes\Route;
use App\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Controllers\SampleController;
use App\Controllers\PagesController;
use App\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Controllers\ProfileController;

Route::get('/login', [PagesController::class, 'login']);
Route::get('/signup', [PagesController::class, 'signup']);
Route::get('/create', [AuthController::class, 'signaction']);
Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);

Route::get('/profile', function($email) {
            $email = $_GET['u'];
        echo $email;
});
```

This is the htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN Route

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END Route
```

Now my question is how can i grab the value from the url using the GET superglobal
I will be glad if this problem would be solved for me. Thanks a lot people for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php mvc getting user details from his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70994380/php-mvc-getting-user-details-from-his-profile)

Comment: You still haven't answered all the question I asked the last time you posted this exact question. How would you call your callback without the _required_ argument `$email`? Where is it set? How do you get it and pass it when executing the callback function/method?  We have _absolutely no idea_ how your router works or how it executes the callbacks. I also don't see how your `ProfileController` is related here either since your router only seem to have a closure as callback.

Comment: first of all i used the function to get a specific method that i called from a controller. Now if u look at that ProfileController i created a method called profile which works with the user profile. Now i tested this GET superglobal in two places in other to know whether it would work. But to me it seems i just have to try it out in the ProfileController instead. The $email variable is the argument i passed to the created method in other to user and grab the output http:://localhost:3000/profile?u=werner from the url before i now pass it on to my model. Hope i answered ur question

Comment: the web.php file i created is where all the called routes and controllers pass through just as in laravel sir

Comment: No, that didn't clarify anything, tbh. It's very unclear what you mean. I still have no clue what the argument `$email` contains or how it's passed into the callback. And in the code you have posted here, I don't see how `ProfileController::profile()` would be called at all since your route only contain a closure. You mention Laravel, but Laravel needs to have some URL parameter to be able to pass data into the controller, like: `get('/profile/{email}'` while your route doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: i would be glad if u give me a better clue on how to make this happen neglecting the way i did it.  you might still have better ideas on how it can be possible using your own format

Comment: With the question and the posted code, I honestly don't 100% understand the issue or exactly where you're stuck, so it's hard to give any examples. I don't see how your callbacks can be executed at all atm and if the question is about how to have a router with parameters and how to pass them to the controller, it's too broad (and unanswerable without knowing how your router currently works). If it simply is how to fetch a value from the query string, your code should already do that (from the `$_GET`-global).

Comment: let update the code i posted it might give you some little clue

Comment: i have just updated the code. i think it might give you some clue on how it works

Comment: actually ive worked on everything to make the code functional. And its working perfectly ok. Am just stuck on how on how i am going to grab the parameters from the url. i already updated the code right now.

Comment: I think you missed: _"and if the question is about how to have a router with parameters and how to pass them to the controller, it's too broad "_. We would need to basically write that function for you to be able to write a proper answer. A hint though: use regex. You can check how other routers work to get some ideas (or just use any of the tried and tested routers out there)

Comment: writing the function wouldnt be possible?

Comment: you can still give me a hint on how i would write the functions. let me try it out. Also is there anyway i can get ur contact or any means of messaging u?

Comment: _"you can still give me a hint"_ - That's _literally_ what I did in my last comment. Good luck, but I'm done here...

Comment: aiit no problems